# How to make "the" optional in my cucumber BDD Step Definitions?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumber-java

I'd like to match either of the following BDD:

```
Then the response status should be "200"
Then response status should be "200"
```

**I want to make "the" optional**. I want these two rules to map to the SAME step.

Here is my attempt, but it doesn't work:

```
@Then("^(?:the | )response status should be \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void the_response_status_should_be(String arg1) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work ... `"^(?:the )*response status should be \"([^\"]*)\"$"`

Comment: That didn't work, but adding `?:` did! I'll edit your answer ;D

Answer (score 2):

Using Cucumber Expression this can be done quite easily just by surrounding the optional text with parentheses like this:

```
(the )response status should be "200"
```

[Read more...](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/#optional-text)